# How can I see the change log of a directory with TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I'm interested in seeing the latest changes that landed to a solution with TFS (I'm using Visual Studio). However, I can't seem to find the option: using *View History* on a solution or project brings up the history of the file itself. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you right click on folder the containing a solution in the ***Source Control Explorer window*** you'll see all changesets. It's obvious but I had to ask for it too. I am using TFS2010/VS2010.

**Edit**
Here are the steps:
Team/Connect to Team Foundation Server / select Team Project/ in Team Explorer dblclick on Source Control and in Source Control Explore right click folder containing your solution select  View History and here you are.

Answer (score 2):

The View History command will list you all the changesets where the file/directory was changed (add/move/content changed, deleted, etc.).

So if you do a View History on a .sln or .csproj file you'll see only the changes that were made inside the file's content, not on the "Visual Studio Item" and its related item.

To sum up, the View History command is only a **File System** history, there's not a smarter logic out there.

**EDIT**

The only way to know what changed inside a solution or project is to do a View History on the common denominator (i.e. the directory that contains everything you want to view history). But it'll still be a File System kind of History.

There's not Logical History for Solution and Projects in Visual Studio. For instance you can't know what files where added to a given project your viewing the history from two given versions. Or what projects were added/removed in the solution.

All the pieces are there (because all the changes are stored in the .csproj or .sln), but the feature itself that parses the content and retrieve the logic you want to see doesn't exist. (by the way, it's a great feature and I agree it should be there).

Bottom line: TFS/Visual Studio gives you two history system:

1. Based on the source control/file system, by displaying changesets.
2. Based on the source control/file system, by displaying labels.

That's all...

Comment: That's a great explanation of the behavior I'm experiencing, but is there a solution for what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on folder in solution explorer, and choose View History. Then you can see all the Changesets listed that apply to that directory. Then right click a particular changeset and choose `Changeset details...` to see what changes occurred in that changeset.

Comment: For projects and solutions, this seems to bring up the history of the project/solution files themselves.

Comment: @Zneak - I just tried this on a solution file, and it showed me the files for a specific changeset. The .sln file was part of that, but it also included other files that were changed as part of the changeset.

Comment: I'm afraid we don't have the same View History feature. Mine really just shows the changesets that modified the solution file. Am I missing something more?

Comment: @zneak - Interesting...we are running TFS 2008 with SP1, are you running earlier (or maybe even later) version?

Comment: where can I see the version number? That aside, shouldn't it be more of a client feature than a server feature? In which case I'm using VS2010.

Comment: @zneak - Not sure how to see TFS version number client side, I just know we are on 2008 since I installed it :).

Comment: @zneak: You're right. It only shows the history of those changesets that actually caused a modification to the solution files.